# Fancybox and JQuery Accordian Won't Work on the Same Page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancy box and a jquery accordian on the same page. Each works independently but not together. There is a conflict somewhere. I've looked at several forums and posts, but cannot fit a fix. Some say to put the jquery-ui scripts first. That didn't work. Some said to combine the functions into one script. That didn't work.

Here is the head section of my page.

```
`<head>
`<title>Transportation Business Group</title>
`<meta name="KEYWORDS" content="International business group.">
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/voglobalstyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection">
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection">
`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

`<script src="/scripts/jQuery-UI/1.8.17/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/jQuery-UI/1.8.17/Content/themes/base/twisty.ui.css"
    type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/Plugins/fancybox/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/Plugins/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/Plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
`<script src="/scripts/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*
        *   Examples - images
        */
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            navigation: true,
            collapsible: true,
            active: true
        });
        $("a#MikeFormal").fancybox({
            'titleShow': true,
            'titlePosition': 'over',

            'autoScale': false
        });

        $("a#MikeInformal").fancybox({
            'titleShow': true,
            'titlePosition': 'over',

            'autoScale': false
        });



    });
</script>
 </head>
```

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins include a version of jQuery in the download for practical reasons but you only need to load a single instance (the latest version possible) . Additionally, jQuery has to be loaded first, before any plugin and before even jQuery UI.

In your case, you are loading jQuery twice and after jQuery UI. Use a single instance and place it before of any plugin in your document.

Also, I don't see that you are loading the fancybox CSS file anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your script order should be:

```
<!-- Jquery must load first -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/jQuery-UI/1.8.17/Content/themes/base/twisty.ui.css"
    type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/Plugins/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery/Plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
```

I noticed that you're also using a much older version of jquery core with the most recent version of jQuery UI.
The second thing I noticed was that you are loading the jQuery Core and UI js files from your local server, rather than a CDN. I've replaced them with the Google CDN versions.

For Fancybox, you might want to also look at loading them from the [CDNJS](http://www.cdnjs.com/) but I've left them as is for now.